# checking whether a checkbox list item is selected and display a textbox

Tags: asp.net

Please dont cut down the points just going by the question. I have tried but did not find solution . My checkbox list is in user control . IT IS NOT IN ASPX page and the user control is a popup . In the popup i have checkbox list .It looks like whenever

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkdeadhd" CssClass="chkboxlist" CellSpacing="2"       
   AutoPostBack="true"    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>ITEM1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>ITEM2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdeadhdtrn" Width="45px" 
     Visible="false"
     CssClass="  input-text masked-input-time"
    ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**PROBLEM**
   whenever i check  ITEM2 ,Textbox  needs to be displayed.

Again it is not in the ASPX PAGE .So server side solutions will not work .It is in the usercontrol which is a popup.I understand it is an ajax call and needs to be done though jquery/javascript.

1. Check whether item2 is selected
2. If yes create a textbox .

Comment: Not that you should, but you can still use a server side solution if it's a user control.

Comment: Can you explain with the code Abe Miessler